# Buffer to String malformed coding (Native ZLIB Compression - Node.js)

Tags: node.js, json, buffer, zlib

Hello I am taking JSON passing it through zlib for compressing, storing it as a buffer in a flat file database, and then reading it and sending it out.

Except my problem is the data is all sorts of crazy characters. I've tried .toString() Ive tried the official StringDecoder from Node. I've tried a lot of things but I can't seem to get it in any format other then the .toJSON readable as a JSON buffer when I actually need the outputted final JSON.

Ideas?

WRITING TO FLAT FILE DB

```
export const writeCollection = (index, timespan, data) => {
  zlib.gzip(JSON.stringify(data), (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log({ err });
    } else {
      const keyName = dbCollections.gzip[index].add({
        result
      });
      collectionKeys.gzip[index] = keyName;
      writeLogging(timespan, keyName, index, "gzip");
    }
  });

  zlib.brotliCompress(JSON.stringify(data), (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log({ err });
    } else {
      const keyName = dbCollections.brotli[index].add({
        result
      });
      collectionKeys.brotli[index] = keyName;
      writeLogging(timespan, keyName, index, "brotli");
    }
  });
};
```

READING FROM FLAT FILE DB

```
export const readCollection = (index, encoding) => {
  const encodedRead = encoding.includes("br")
    ? dbCollections.brotli[index].all()
    : dbCollections.gzip[index].all();
  return encodedRead[0].result;
};
```

TRYING TO CONVERT TO JSON

```
export const testGetQuakeData = (req, res) => {
  const encoding = req.headers["accept-encoding"];

  try {
    const data = readCollection(0, encoding);
    console.log(data)
    const json = decoder.write(Buffer.from(data));
    console.log(json)
    // res.set({
    //   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    //   'Content-Encoding': encoding.includes('br') ? 'br' : "gzip",
    // })
    res.send(json)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log({ err });
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

FORGOT TO UNZIP WITH ZLIB!

```
 export const testGetQuakeData = (req, res) => {
  const encoding = req.headers["accept-encoding"];

  try {
    const data = readCollection(0, encoding);
    encoding.includes("br")
      ? zlib.brotliDecompress(data, (err, result) => {
          err ? res.status(500).send(err) : res.send(decoder.write(result));
        })
      : zlib.unzip(data, (err, result) => {
          err ? res.status(500).send(err) : res.send(decoder.write(result));
        });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log({ err });
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
};
```

HERES THE FUTURE PROD FUNCTION!

```
export const testGetCompressedQuakeData = (req, res) => {
  const encoding = req.headers["accept-encoding"];
  try {
    const data = readCollection(0, encoding);
    encoding.includes("br")
      ? res.writeHead(200, {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Content-Encoding": "br",
          "Content-Length": data.length,
        })
      : res.writeHead(200, {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Content-Encoding": "gzip",
          "Content-Length": data.length,
        })
    res.end(data)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log({ err });
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
};
```

Content Length 6319 (Brotli) vs 63148 (JSON)
Brotli Compression for the win!